# Regular expression in Javascript to find img tag with src="", means no image specified

Tags: javascript, html, image

My requirement is to remove all img tags with doesnt have img specified in it. I tried doing with help of regular expression, that is `content.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g,"")`, but this removes all img tags, I want to validate this to replace only with empty img tags. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to use regular expression for this task? A loop for the `<img>` tags would do it easily.

Comment: Can you try `getElementsByTagName('img')` and for each of the elements you check if the attribute `src` is empty? Then you can remove it from it's parent.

Comment: i am not a super hero in regular expressions but - what i can suggest is look for src attribute in image tag. this might help you

Comment: Regular expressions are the wrong tool for the job in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do:

```
var imgTags = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i = 0; i < imgTags.length; i++) {
if(imgTags[i].getAttribute("src") === "")
    imgTags[i].parentNode.removeChild(imgTags[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

           $('body').find('img').each(function(i) { 
               var src=$(this).attr('src');
               if(src=="")
              {
                $(this).remove();
               }
              }); 

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: It is correct, but the asker won't use JQuery (no tag specified).